# Bash scripts exits on entering docker container

Tags: linux, bash, performance, docker, containers

Im trying to create a bash script for setting up docker and an application on a fresh server.

pretty fresh to bash itself but i think ive got the just

heres a snippet where my issue lies -

#

```
docker run -d --name application -p 80:80 -d  tutum/apache-php
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name=database --
env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password1" mysql:latest
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Docker is all done - run docker ps -a to see all created 
containers!"
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Moving onto installing application into app container!"
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
docker exec -it application bash

apt-get update & apt-get install git & cd /var/www/html
```

#

on the line - `docker exec -it application bash`

It enters the container as expected but the bash script then stops because of this meaning the following commands after don't run

Is there anyway I can get around this? I don't think there is but in case there are any bash wizards out there!

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify: are you trying to run `apt-get update & apt-get install git & cd /var/www/html` inside the container?

Comment: Also, please provide the output of `docker logs application` so that we can have a better overview of the issue :)

Comment: Yeah fotis thats correct - on the docker exec command the bash script stops/exits there for not running the rest of the commands i have to run after this step

Comment: `apt-get update & ....` is very differnt from `apt-get update && ...` A single `&` runs the preceding cmd in the background and then tries to start the next command immediately. That doesn't make sense. Switch to `&&` for all on that line. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the as i didnt know before! however it didnt help me out much here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what `-it` is supposed to do. It means a interactive bash and it will only exit when you are done with it. Change your code as below

```
docker run -d --name application -p 80:80 -d  tutum/apache-php
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name=database --
env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password1" mysql:latest
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Docker is all done - run docker ps -a to see all created 
containers!"
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Moving onto installing application into app container!"
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------"

docker exec application bash -c "apt-get update & apt-get install git -y"
docker exec -it application bash -c "cd /var/www/html; exec bash"
```

Answer (score 1):

A few remarks here:

It's better to use `docker exec -it application /bin/bash` (providing the path to the bash executable) because in containers usually the $PATH isn't set, so you're probably getting an error.

Also, the command `docker exec -it application /bin/bash` will enter `interactive` mode, which allocates a command line for you, so the script will stop execution there and wait for you to enter some command at `stdin`.

Now, if you want to run a series of commands in a docker container, you can't do it by providing them inside the script.

One thing you can do, is create a script file (eg. `myscript.sh`) that you can mount as a volume to your `docker run` (eg. `docker run -v /Users/Calvin/myscript.sh:/myscript.sh`. Another thing you can do is provide the commands via `-c`, so `docker exec application /bin/sh -C 'apt-get update ....'` (notice I'm not using the `-it` flag).

Finally, the best practice for what you're trying to achieve is provide a `Dockerfile`, so that you run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install -y git` when the container is being built, and not every time you bring it up.

Sample Dockerfile:

```
FROM tutum/apache-php
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git
```

and then use `docker build -t .`

More on Dockerfile here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: Thanks for the post! you make some good points in it - i am working towards a dockerfile so yeah that makes sense! i understand the -it command now was just a lack of understand so with all this i can get what i want to achive now - cheers! :)

Comment: Welcome to the beautiful world of Docker @CalvinTaylor I promise, it's amazing :)